# Struts 2: options for tree controls

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, struts2

We have an application written with Struts 2.1.8.1 that uses the [Dojo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) plug-in for the tabbed panels.  We need to add functionality to this application that provides tree support.  So basically, the application has a top level menu, clicking on each item will display a set of tabs for that item.  Some tabs will need to display a tree control where clicking on items in the tree will change the contents of a `div` to the right of the tree.  I also need the tree to maintain state, so if I leave the screen and come back the tree is expanded to the same state with the same item selected.

I was trying to get the Dojo `<sx:tree>` tag to work, and I was running into a lot of problems.  After doing some more research, I learned that Dojo has been deprecated with Struts 2.2.1.  It also seems like people are moving away from tag-based solutions and moving more toward JavaScript solutions.  Is this considered the current best practice?

I've been reading a lot about jQuery, but it doesn't look like it has any support for a tree.  I've also found some third-party commercial JavaScript tree controls.  Two of them I'm looking at are http://www.treemenu.net/ and http://www.javascripttreemenu.com/.

Are there better options?

Comment: I've expanded the tags to include some input from jquery members such that they might be able to point out some nice tree options. You may want to further expand the tags to see if another frame work would fit you better ie: dojo, ext, prototype.

Answer (score 1):

I've found working in a JavaScript library (jQuery) to be much more efficient than using the Struts 2 Dojo Ajax tags.  I don't use the Struts 2 jQuery plugin (I have no idea what it does). I just include the script the same way any script would be.  This is coming from someone with very little JavaScript experience. The learning curve is lower than trying to figure out the bloody tag library, and then the flexibility... there is no comparison.

As for the current trend, this is what I've seen on the Struts 2 news group. The use of a JavaScript framework over a tag library has been voiced numerous times by Dave Newton (author of Apache Struts 2 web application development and Struts 2 contributer), probably others but his name stood out to me because his book is on the desk!  But for a better feeling of consensus it might be best to write the news group directly.

Just like Struts 2, jQuery is a tightly focused framework.  For this reason plugins are the norm, not the exception so don't be afraid to use one.  jQuery is about accessing the DOM in a sensible way (using CSS selectors, so if you know CSS you know half of what's important) and then performing simple operations on the DOM. From there people have built all kinds of nice things.

I have not used it, but http://www.jstree.com/ looks pretty.

Here is a page talking about [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI), and that they will include a tree plugin perhaps in their next release. It also lists several tree plugins that they recommend. http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree

Comment: +1 I also use jQuery directly, rather than through an S2 plug-in. Whichever framework you decide on, try to use the framework directly. Its a skill that will serve you well if you ever need to work in a different environment.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! What both of you are saying makes a lot of sense.